# how to pass two class intent value to another one class?

Tags: android, android-intent

I my app i have two class are passing a intent value to another one class ,but in a Received class ,how to set the two intent values  to one same variable

manes, first  one Activity  pass the intent to that class , and after another Activity  pass the value to same class and in Received class set the intent value to same variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8610916/320111

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference to maintain Data. 
U can save your value from following method in Both Activities

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

U can retrive the value in any Activity.

```
private void showPreferences(String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedPref = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
        myTextView.setText(savedPref);
       }
```

Still If u want to Use Intent.U can use it.
Add Two of your Sender Activity

Pass the values:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_item", item);
startActivity(intent);
```

here, value of "item" be varied as u pass it. 
You can retrieve it in Receiver Activity:

Get the Values in SecondActivity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String string = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_item");
```

Here, string will get last Sender Activity Intent's "item" value.