# Return message from called phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, return-value

I have two apps created using Phonegap and, at the moment, they run only on Android devices. I call app2 from app1 using Intent. How can I have a return message (or something like this) from app2 to app1? 
Thanks.

Omar

Answer (score 0):

So app2 is somehow launching an intent to open up app1 and you want to pass some information from app2 into app1? Intents have a `putExtra` method that lets you attach more information to them that you can later read in app1; see this stackoverflow question: [How do I create an android Intent that carries data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610880/how-do-i-create-an-android-intent-that-carries-data)

Now, getting this to work with Cordova might be a bit more tricky - how are you launching the intent? If it is some sort of phonegap plugin, there is probably a way to use `putExtra`.