# Android gcm notification open fragment

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

When I click, The fragment doesn't open. What am I doing wrong? This is my gcm code. I don't see any error in log chat. The notification works, I think there is not any problem.

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


         extras=intent.getExtras();

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm= GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);


        String messageType=gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        mes=extras.getString("title");
        //showToast();
        Log.e("Gcm Reciever : ", "(" + messageType + ")" + extras.getString("title")+"  /// ");
        //Log.e("Messaj : ",mes);
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        showToast();
    }
    public void showToast(){

        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(),0);

        Notification noti=new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentText(extras.getString("message"))
                .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mylogoticker)
                .setTicker("Evren Time")
                .getNotification();

        noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        noti.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bildirim);
        noti.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
        noti.ledOnMS = 300;
        noti.ledOffMS = 1000;
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

        noti.contentIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this,MyFragment.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager manage=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manage.notify(0, noti);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pIntent you left the "new Intent()" empty

```
    PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(),0);
```

Also, instead of calling a fragment directly you should instead call the hosting activity. This is because the fragment doesn't exist on it's own and has to be attached to an Activity.

Check this question [How to open fragment page, when pressed a notification in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608627/how-to-open-fragment-page-when-pressed-a-notification-in-android)

Please note that it is highly advisable to migrate from GCM to FCM here is a guide to help you https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm