# How to navigate from Service to a Navigation Fragment using probably Pending Intent?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, navigation-architecture

I'm trying to open a fragment with args from my notification.
Actually, in my case, I have Audio Player running with Foreground Service with Notification and now I want to navigate to my fragment for that specific Audio by passing Audio Id when a user clicks to the Notification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can open your activity with `PendingIntent` then open your fragment via handling the `Intent` inside of your activity.

or this answer from similar topic

NavDeepLinkBuilder:

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
                     .setComponentName(YourActivity::class.java)
                     .setGraph(R.navigation.your_nav_graph)
                     .setDestination(R.id.your_destination)
                     .setArguments(bundle)
                     .createPendingIntent()

//then

notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

Comment: this is clumsy when having much navigation. Didn't Navigation Architecture guys make any Utils for this? I mean handling Navigation with Intent easier.

Comment: You can look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245317/11181035

Comment: Oh did it! Thanks that should be the answer to my question.

Comment: This was really really fast answer, you guys are awesome... thanks again.

Comment: This recreates my fragment. Is there a way to have my retained fragment spawned instead?

Comment: I am not able to recreate the backstack with this soultion. I have Fragment  A -> B -> C -> D -> E when I use this solution the graph is only A -> E . Any idea?

Comment: Unable to start activity, inside my fragment its showing null pointer exception

Comment: I used NavDeepLinkBuilder within my service and pass the service context and It didn't work can you tell how you used NavDeepLinkBuilder in your foreground service.

Comment: When targeting the new Android S, you have to use `.createTaskStackBuilder()
            .getPendingIntent(0, FLAG_IMMUTABLE)` instead of `.createPendingIntent()` otherwise your app will crash due to the new Pending Intent restrictions.

Comment: How do you create a bundle to pass as an argument? How do you get data from notifications?