# Launch a particular Fragment using Navigation component when tapped on Notification that is sent from WorkManager

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

I'm sending a daily notification to the user based on a condition from the [Worker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker) that is launched using BroadcastReceiver. From `Worker` I only have `context` for sending notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID).apply {
    setContentTitle(...)
    setContentText(...)
    setContentIntent(pendingIntent(context)) 
}.build()
```

How do I create `PendingIntent` for launching a particular fragment using Navigation component?

I tried this:

```
fun pendingIntent(context: Context): PendingIntent {
    val navController = NavController(context.applicationContext)
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.your_navigation)
    return navController.createDeepLink()
        .setDestination(R.id.yourFragment)
        .createPendingIntent()
}
```

But I get following exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating package.name:navigation/your_navigation line 7
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:90)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:425)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:407)
        at 
        ......
        at package.name.Worker.doWork(Worker.kt:15)
        at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find Navigator with name "fragment". You must call NavController.addNavigator() for each navigation type.
        at androidx.navigation.NavigatorProvider.getNavigator(NavigatorProvider.java:98)
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:100)
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:81)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:425) 
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:407) 
        at package.name.NotificationKt.pendingIntent(Notification.kt:57) 
        at package.name.buildNotificationFor(Notification.kt:50) 
        at package.name.showNotificationFor(Notification.kt:22) 
        at package.name.doWork(Worker.kt:15) 
        at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:85)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [Create an explicit deep link documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#explicit), you should be using the [`NavDeepLinkBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDeepLinkBuilder) class:

```
fun pendingIntent(context: Context): PendingIntent {
    return NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
       .setGraph(R.navigation.your_navigation)
       .setDestination(R.id.android)
       .createPendingIntent()
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot, great to see you answering my question. You have been a huge help here on SO, throughout my learning.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! Best of luck going forward :)

Comment: I have tried to use this code like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUFNJ.png , but when I click notification, it will bring me to home, not to inbox destination that I want. the destination_inbox is a menu in my bottom navigation bar like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF0UR.png. am I missing something ? :(

Comment: @Alexa289 - `destination_inbox` needs to be a destination in your navigation graph XML. If deep linking to a destination in your graph isn't working, you could always [file a bug against Navigation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828) with a minimal sample project that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yup, I believe the inbox destination is already in xml graph like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EXsb.png , in gradle I am using  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0" and implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"

Comment: @ShahrozKhan91 yup, If you have more than one Activity, then you should add .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245317/9605341

Comment: Hi, how do I achieve this when the app is running in the background?

Comment: @Yeldar.N - on Android 10+ devices you [cannot start an activity from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). The guidance there of starting a [time-sensitive notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive) applies to all API levels as the recommended pattern. All of the PendingIntents used there can be generated with `NavDeepLinkBuilder`.

Comment: @Alexa289 - check out the answer provided [bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66397131/7680523)

Comment: @Yeldar.N I had the same question.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I think the bigger issue with this method is that a new instance of the activity is created. Say there is an app running in the foreground and the user clicks on the notification, this would lead to a duplicate activity instead of the existing one.

Comment: If you have multiple destinations then don't forget to add `setComponentName(DestinationActivity::class.java`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is **more suited** for the question asked by @Alexa289 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63589481/how-to-move-to-a-certain-fragment-destination-after-clicking-push-notification-m?noredirect=1&lq=1) **but** since the question was **closed** on the basis that this is a similar question and answer provided by @ianhanniballeke should suffice. I am compelled to write the answer here. The answer provided by @ianhanniballake is brillant but it only work for certain condition when dealing with `onMessageReceived()` of a class extending `FirebaseMessagingService()`. When the activity is in foreground, the service provide activity based context hence the code works fine, but when the activity is not in foreground, the class provide service based context, hence the pendingIntent created from NavDeepLinkBuilder works differently. So here goes my solution for the non-foreground cases.
Firstly, create the pendingIntent through the usual way

```
fun pendingIntent(context: Context): PendingIntent {
    return NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
       .setGraph(R.navigation.your_navigation)
       .setDestination(R.id.android)
       .createPendingIntent()
}
```

then you need to catch the pending intent through intent filter in the android manifest like this

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="*TheClassNameOfFragmentYourDestinationPointsTo*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Then from the home fragment, you can grab the intent that start the activity like this

```
val intent = (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.intent
```

From the **intent** you can extract the extras in the bundle then navigate to the fragment you wish to like this

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.android)
```