# Can NavDeepLinkBuilder reuse an existing instance of an Activity instead of creating a new instance?

Tags: android, android-notifications

My end goal is to open a fragment on click of a notification. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608627/how-to-open-fragment-page-when-pressed-a-notification-in-android/55245317#comment120233569_55245317) answer seemed useful but NavDeepLinkBuilder creates a new instance of the activity which is not what I was looking for.

I also found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043699/2188242) which sends out intents to the existing activity but I'm not sure how to bring up the destination fragment from the activity.

Comment: We have the same problem - did you find a solution?

Comment: I believe my understanding of fragments was wrong. Yes, a new activity is created by the `NavDeepLinkBuilder` (with the specified fragment). So I ended up handling the fragment's state in the DB and re-populated it at the time of fragment creation. Lot of extra state handling but no other way (from what I understand).