# Dynamically display a layout based on a value from a spinner

Tags: android, textbox, spinner

Using Android Studio 1.1.0.  Here is what I'm trying to accomplish...

I have a screen set up that will collect the # of players for a game.  Based on the value from that spinner, I want to display X amount of text boxes on my next activity to capture the player names.

How can I set this up?

Comment: So is the part you are unsure of how to dynamically generate text boxes?

Comment: Post the code you have already put together.  What I am assuming your question to be.  You have a spinner containing the number of players.  When selecting the number you want to start another activity containing x amount of text fields for the number selected within spinner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Data between Activitys by setting them as an Extra in the Intent. This Question explains how: [How do I create an android Intent that carries data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610880/how-do-i-create-an-android-intent-that-carries-data)

If you have a List in which you store Strings for the Player Names you could do that for example like the following:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("playerNames", yourList);
```

In your next Activity you could then create a ListView (or GridView or whatever you think is suitable for this task) in which you show all the Playernames.

Answer (score 0):

First pass this information from your first Activity:

```
 int numberOfPlayers;
```

Get the number of players from your spinner, however you currently do that set it to numberOfPlayers

Then pass this when you start your new Activity

```
 Intent getPlayerNamesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PLayerNamesActivity.class);
 getPlayerNamesIntent.putExtra("NUM_PLAYERS", numberOfPlayers); 
 startActivity(getPlayerNamesIntent);
```

Then in the next Activity onCreate get your Extras

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // Layout should create have something like LinearLAyout with orientation vertical with name android:id="@+id/linearLayoutParent"
      setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);


      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutParent);

     // get the NUmber from extras
     int numberOfPlayers = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NUM_PLAYERS");

    if(numberOfPlayers > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){
           EditText editText = new EditText(this);
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          editText.setLayoutParams(params);
          // Set Tag here, so you can use tag to get the right player later
          editText.setTag("PlayerNumber_" + Integer.toString(i)); 
          layout.addView(editText);

        }
    }
 }
```